# Zen coding for Sublime text 2 , how can I set the shortcuts?

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

As You Know ,Sublime text 2 is a wonderful text Editor .We can use the package control to install package .Zen coding is best one of these packages .But how can I change the key settings ?

Now I just know to spread out the Abbreviation .And how to wrap with Abbreviation ?

Answer (score 6):

On a Mac it is `CTRL Option Return` that opens the Haiku bar at the bottom and you can enter the Koan code. Like: `.box{Hello}*5` which will result in:

```
<div class="box">Hello</div>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change default zen coding key setting you should look into (in Windows) `AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\ZenCoding` folder. You have there a file called `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` that consists of key mappings.

If you want to wrap with abbreviation you should select text to wrap and press `Ctrl + Alt + Enter`. It will open 'Enter Haiku' bar at the bottom. There you can input zen coding.